# Is there a way to change fileupload control file name on submit

Tags: javascript, xpages

Here is my simple xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="File Resource"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{document1.FieldAttachment}">
    </xp:fileUpload>

    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

I want on Submit/Save that it saves fileselected in RichText field but with custom name. In other words whatever user selects to upload I want it be custom name as a file attachment in Notes Document. E.g. user uploads MyPicture.jpg then on Submit/Save it adds the file as an attachment to Notes document but with other name, e.g. Picture1.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change attachment's name on submit. Use fileUpload's property `filename`

```
<xp:fileUpload
    id="fileUpload1"
    value="#{document1.FieldAttachment}"
    useUploadname="false"
    filename="Picture1.jpg">
</xp:fileUpload>
```

[image]

In case you want to *calculate* the attachment name based on uploaded filename you can use `this.value.getClientFileName()` to get the original filename.

Example: add prefix "Picture_" to original filename

```
<xp:fileUpload
    id="fileUpload1"
    value="#{document1.FieldAttachment}"
    useUploadname="false">
    <xp:this.filename><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var fileName = this.value.getClientFileName();
        return "Picture_" + fileName;
    }]]></xp:this.filename>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

Comment: Thank you.. that works.. I just missed that property.. Sorry for stupid question

Comment: You're welcome. It's not a stupid question though. It's not really self-explanatory how to modify original file name for example...